# tikz: specify a point a distance from beginning/end of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 3);
  \draw [fill=blue] (A) circle (0.1);
  \draw [fill=blue] (B) circle (0.1);
  \draw ($(A)!0.1!(B)$) -- ($(A)!0.9!(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output looks nice:

[image]

However, instead of using `$(A)!0.1!(B)$` and `$(A)!0.9!(B)$` I would like to specify the line to be drawn 0.4cm from the beginning to 0.4cm from the end of the path `(A) -- (B)`. How to do it?

Comment: try `($(A)!0.1cm!(B)$)` and `($(A)!0.9cm!(B)$)`

Comment: @AndréC, using `($(A)!0.4cm!(B)$)` and `($(B)!0.4cm!(A)$)` works. I enlarged the distance.

Comment: @AndréC, you are encouraged to provide your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To shorten a path by a distance, you do not even need `calc`. You can just use the `shorten` key.

```
\draw[shorten >=0.4cm,shorten <=0.4cm] (A) -- (B);
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (1, 3);
  \draw [fill=blue] (A) circle (0.1);
  \draw [fill=blue] (B) circle (0.1);
  %\draw ($(A)!0.1!(B)$) -- ($(A)!0.9!(B)$);
  \draw[shorten >=0.4cm,shorten <=0.4cm] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]